# Sideload Typescript / React Office Add-In for Word on Mac

Tags: typescript, macos, visual-studio-code, office-js, office-addins

I followed the MS Office tutorial and created a taskpane add-in with JavaScript and successfully sideloaded it on Word.... then I created a JavaScript add-in with React and was also able to sideload on Word.... now I've created a TypeScript add-in using React and it loads but gives the default message of "Please sideload your add-in to see app body"

I used npm start for the first two... I have tried clearing cache manually and the following commands but still same result:

- npm run dev-server
- npx office-addin-dev-certs install

I am not getting any errors and the terminal displays "sideloading add-in". What am I missing?

Comment: This looks like a problem with the project generator. I suggest you raise this as an issue on the repo: [Office-Addin-TaskPane-React](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane-React/issues).